# Do fonts get downloaded if they've already been @font-faced from another website?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I'm using Open Sans on my site, and I'm noticing from the handy colored dial on Google Web Fonts, that if I want the light, italic, semi bold, bold, and other styles, that it becomes quite a heavy download for the end user.

Is this really a problem with a font as popular as Open Sans? Do browsers download Open Sans all over again every time a website has their own file listed in an @font-face declaration?

Am I incurring expensive HTTP requests, or am I just adding what is missing? So that if a browser already has Open Sans Regular, Italic, and Bold (and bold italic), they're only grabbing Light and Semi Bold from me?

**Preemptive Update** I've used the `local()` expression in my @font-face declaration, and it's given me real bad problems with italic styling, it basically ignores it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use `local()`, which you say you have problems with and which is prone to users having different font files than the one you assume they have, font files are just like any other resource (scripts, images, style-sheets).

They will get cached by browsers, depending on user preferences - this meaning they only get downloaded once and used from cache from that point on, until the cache expires or gets cleaned.

If you define a `@font-face` and specify font files for it, the first format the browser understands from the list of font file formats you list will be downloaded and used. That's why you normally list the lightest formats first and the heaviest last: (`woff2` > `woff` > `ttf` > `svg`).

Please note that if you serve the font files from your server browsers will never use the font-files from, let's say Google, even if they are exactly the same. This gives you the option to serve modified font-files. But if you use font-files from Google, users might already have them cached, and they will be used if they had the exact same download link (same weights, same variants).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! So the performance knock that we incur from heavy fonts is only incurred for first time site visitors. From that point on, they'll just use cached fonts. Unless of course the data gets cleaned from their cache. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and only the first format is downloaded, not all. In addition, they only get downloaded if they are used on an element in your page, not if they are linked, with the only notable exception of IE, which downloads font-files regardless, even if no element in the page uses them.